# How to count the frequency of a string for each row in R

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have a .txt file that looks something like this:

```
rs1 NC AB NC     
rs2 AB NC AA  
rs3 NC NC NC  
...
```

For each row, I would like to count the frequencies of "NC", so that my output will be something like below:

```
rs1 2  
rs2 1  
rs3 3  
...
```

Can someone tell me how to do this in R or in Linux? Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df$count <- rowSums(df[-1] == "NC")
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 count
# 1 rs1 NC AB NC     2
# 2 rs2 AB NC AA     1
# 3 rs3 NC NC NC     3
```

We can use `rowSums` on the matrix that is created from this expression `df[-1] == "NC"`.

Comment: Thanks! : ) Of course not. It also does not work if `df` is an igraph mapping, it also doesn't work if `df` is an orange slice or flat screen tv. Not sure what your point is.

Answer (score 7):

```
dat <- read.table(text="rs1 NC AB NC rs2 AB NC AA rs3 NC NC NC")
dat <- rbind(dat, dat, dat, dat)
```

You can use a rowwise `table` to get the frequencies per row
In this case for row 1 to 4 the frequencies that are equal as i copied the data

```
freq <- apply(dat, 1, table)
    1 2 3 4 # row-number
AA  1 1 1 1
AB  2 2 2 2
NC  6 6 6 6
rs1 1 1 1 1
rs2 1 1 1 1
rs3 1 1 1 1
```

If you want to have aggregated frequencies over all rows use

```
rowSums(freq)
AA  AB  NC rs1 rs2 rs3 
 4   8  24   4   4   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using newer version of dplyr (>=1.0), you can use `rowwise` and `c_across` to sum across columns.

```
dat <- read.table(text="
SNP G1 G2 G3
rs1 NC AB NC
rs2 AB NC AA
rs3 NC NC NC", header=TRUE)

library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(c_across(G1:G3)=="NC"))
#   SNP   G1    G2    G3    Total
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 rs1   NC    AB    NC        2
# 2 rs2   AB    NC    AA        1
# 3 rs3   NC    NC    NC        3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  I had a set of 24 variables which worked under the 1 or missing system (checked or unchecked).  I needed to count them.  the final score was the count of checked variables.

data <-  data %>%
dplyr::mutate(final_score =  24 - rowSums(across(c(
Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6, Var7, Var8, Var9, Var10, Var11, Var12,
Var13, Var14, Var15, Var16, Var17, Var18, Var19, Var20, Var21, Var22, Var23,
Var24),
is.na)))

Notes
These variables were not XXX#, they each had different names, so anything on the order of var1-var24 was not possible.

I could have used var1:var24, but I don't like trusting the order of variables in my data set.