# Add a new column to a tibble and use case_when() with multiple types of replacement values in RHS

Tags: r, dplyr

My repex toy data:

```
(df <- tibble(
  symp_A = c("Yes", NA, NA, "Yes", "No", NA), 
  symp_B = c("Yes", NA, NA, "No", "No", NA), 
  symp_C = c("Yes", NA, NA, "No", "No", "No"), 
  symp_D = c("No", NA, NA, "No", "No", "No"), 
  age = c("56", "74", "58", NA, "36", "63")))

  symp_A symp_B symp_C symp_D age  
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1 Yes    Yes    Yes    No     56   
2 NA     NA     NA     NA     74   
3 NA     NA     NA     NA     58   
4 Yes    No     No     No     NA   
5 No     No     No     No     36   
6 NA     NA     No     No     63
```

I'm looking for a (preferably a `tidy` version) solution, that does the following:

1. Create a new column `col_count` with the following conditions:

   1. go across columns that start with "symp" using `dplyr::start_with()`
   2. if a row has a `Yes` then place the count of total `Yes`s in `col_count`
   3. if a row has only `No`, OR `No` + `NA`s, then place `0`
   4. if a row is all `NA` then place `NA`

so the desired output would look like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  symp_A symp_B symp_C symp_D age   count_col
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 Yes    Yes    Yes    No     56            3
2 NA     NA     NA     NA     74           NA
3 NA     NA     NA     NA     58           NA
4 Yes    No     No     No     NA            1
5 No     No     No     No     36            0
6 NA     NA     No     No     63            0
```

My attempt:

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(count_col = purrr::pmap_dbl(#new col, map to
  dplyr::select(., starts_with("symp")), ~ #cols that starts with symp
    dplyr::case_when( #define conditions
      any(c(...) == "Yes") ~ {rowSums(.=="Yes", na.rm=TRUE)}, #if any Yes, tally Yes
      any(c(...) == "No") ~ 0,#not overwriting first condition, tally No
    TRUE ~ NA_real_))) #catch all NA cases and place NA
```

errors:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `count_col`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
ℹ Input `count_col` is `purrr::pmap_dbl(...)`.
```

I can get the desired output using a not so clean long way:

```
df$yes_count <- rowSums(select(df, tidyselect::starts_with("symp"))=="Yes", na.rm=TRUE) #temp yes sum column
df$no_count <- rowSums(select(df, tidyselect::starts_with("symp"))=="No", na.rm=TRUE) #temp no sum column

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(count_col = #new column
                  dplyr::case_when( #conditions:
                    yes_count > 0 ~ yes_count, #if any are Yes, then use the sum
                    no_count > 0 ~ 0, #if any is No (with or without NA), use "0". Won't overwrite first conditions 
                    TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% #everything else (all NA), put NA
  dplyr::select(-yes_count, -no_count) #remove temp columns
```

But I'd really like to know how to get my first approach to work. Admittedly the `map_` business is very new to me so my guess is that my RHS conditions in `case_when` probably are breaking a requirements.

Comment: Not tidy: `rowSums(df[, grepl("^symp_*", colnames(df)) ] == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32618503/680068

Comment: Hi @zx8754, thank you for your suggestion. However, your approach here doesn't quite get the desired output as the first 2 instances of 0s need to actually be 'NA's because the whole row is NA. This conditions is actually the reason why other approaches I read here (including in your provided link) didn't quite get me all the way, and why I posted this as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(col_count = rowSums(select(., starts_with('symp')) == 'Yes', na.rm = TRUE))

#  symp_A symp_B symp_C symp_D age   col_count
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Yes    Yes    Yes    No     56            3
#2 NA     NA     NA     NA     74            0
#3 NA     NA     NA     NA     58            0
#4 Yes    No     No     No     NA            1
#5 No     No     No     No     36            0
#6 NA     NA     No     No     63            0
```

The above gives 0 if all are `NA`, to get `NA` for all `NA`'s you can do :

```
df %>%
  mutate(col_count = rowSums(select(., starts_with('symp')) == 'Yes', na.rm = TRUE) * 
                     NA^!rowSums(!is.na(select(., starts_with('symp')))))


# symp_A symp_B symp_C symp_D age   col_count
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Yes    Yes    Yes    No     56            3
#2 NA     NA     NA     NA     74           NA
#3 NA     NA     NA     NA     58           NA
#4 Yes    No     No     No     NA            1
#5 No     No     No     No     36            0
#6 NA     NA     No     No     63            0
```

---

Using `pmap_dbl` we can write this as :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(count_col = purrr::pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with("symp")), ~ 
    case_when( 
      all(is.na(c(...))) ~ NA_integer_,
      TRUE ~ sum(c(...) == 'Yes', na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Thanks @ronak-shah, that works perfectly! Your approach is very creative and certainly has me down a rabbit hole trying to understand how/why NA^FALSE = 1, but it works!  Do you have any suggestions on how to make my original (not as advanced) approach work using `map` and `case_when`? I know it's longer with more overhead but it is a bit more beginner-friendly and in the future cases where I need to add more specific conditions it might be easier to customize.

Comment: Will certainly do @ronak-shah. Sorry I prematurely pressed enter and had to edit my original comment to ask for a bit more help. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have updated the answer to use `pmap_dbl` @mestaki

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again @RonakShah! That works perfectly.